# Overlay over multiple pages on Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I trying to build a Windows Phone 8 Application which is able to sync data from a webservice.

While I'm syncing the data I want to display a little Popup / overlay / flyout but I still want to be able to navigate between my pages while my overlay persists between this pages.

I did this successfully with a Windows RT App: I simply added a Frame-Control on a RootPage which also display the flyout. I navigated then within this frame and the flyout was always there.

How can I achieve this goal within a Windows Phone 8 Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as you did on Windows8 which is to restyle the ``RootApplicationFrame to add your indicator. For an example see http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/07/creating-a-global-progressindicator-experience-using-the-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-beta-2/

Or you could just use the progress indicator in the system tray of the page to add indication there. This is probably the most common approach taken in apps. See how at http://blog.duc.as/2011/10/08/using-the-system-tray-to-show-progress-in-windows-phone-7-mango/